# Connecting NodeMCU with OV7076 camera

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu

I am trying to connect an OV7076 camera with a NodeMCU, but there are no pin diagram available for it. As NodeMCU has 4 MB storage and 128 KB  memory, is there any possibility to use it?

[AI thinker esp8266mod](https://bennthomsen.files.wordpress.com/2015/12/nodemcu_pinout_700-2.png)

[Omnivision OV7076](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/fh0AAOxyUylTVi8n/$_3.JPG?set_id=2)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot connect an [OV7076](https://www.voti.nl/docs/OV7670.pdf) camera with NodeMCU because OV7076 got 4 analog pins (VGA) and on the other hand NodeMCU got only one analog pin.